# Alloc/init in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using [DYRateView](https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView) to display a star rating view in a custom `UITableViewCell` class. An instance of DYRateView (subclass of UIView) is allocated and initialized in my `layoutSubviews' method.

Is it a bad practice to alloc/init the view in `layoutSubviews'? When the cell is reused, does it alloc/init in every cell or reuse the view?

.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet DYRateView *rateView;
```

.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 60, 160, 20) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];
    NSLog(@"created");

rateView.padding = 10;
rateView.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
rateView.editable = YES;
rateView.delegate = self;
rateView.rate = _rating;
[self.contentView addSubview:rateView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to allocate it in `layoutSubviews`, however you are doing it **every time** `layoutSubviews` is called, and it will be called more frequently than just after an allocation. So, the way you have it now will leak memory badly (unless you are using ARC). Furthermore, you will be constantly adding new `rateView` objects to your `contentView` on every invocation, with rather undesirable consequences.

Since the subview is owned by the cell view, if the cell view is reused, it too will be reused.

Instead, check if the subview exists or not, and allocate accordingly.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if ( rateView == nil ) {
        rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]];

        // rest of rateView set up here

       [self.contentView addSubview:rateView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will just reuse it. You can test it yourself

NSLog(@"Layout subviews, retain count is %d", rateView.retainCount);

Although, why don't you do this in the init method of the custom cell? And just set the frame in layoutSubviews? It looks cleaner.

Comment: Are you referring to this method? `-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

Comment: For some reason, when I implement this method, it never gets called. Could this be b/c I use storyboard?

Comment: Possibly, does the -(id)init {} get called? All you have to do is see in cellForRow how the cell is being created.